# What does a vertical line through the top and middle portion of an equals sign mean?

Tags: inequality, education

I came across a new symbol in the paper [Design-order, non-conformal low-Mach fluid algorithms using a hybrid CVFEM/DG approach by Stefan P. Domino](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999118300172). What does this symbol mean? It looks like it's being used as an equals sign here...

[image]

Here is the set of equations for context:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This looks like $\pm$ ("plus or minus") to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same $\pm$ as used in the well-known formula for the roots of a quadratic polynomial,

$$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$